# BigQueryOperator in spark - can't write array struct to bigquery table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have a field that is of type `RECORD` and in `REPEATED` mode, a column called `actions`.  In Spark, I have a schema defined as

```
val action: StructType = (new StructType)
    .add("id", StringType)
    .add("name", StringType)
    .add("last", StringType)

val actionsList = new ArrayType(action, true)

val finalStruct: StructType = (new StructType)
    .add("record", StringType)
    .add("d", StringType)
    .add("actions", actionsList)
```

This is how my schema is defined, then I simply read it in and write it to bigquery.

```
val df = spark.read.schema(finalStruct).json(rdd)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("myData")
val finalDf = sqlContext.sql("SELECT record as my_rec, d as inc_date, actions from myData")
finalDf.write.mode("append").format("bigquery")...save()
```

However, when I attempt to write the dataframe, I get the error -

```
BigQuery error was provided Schema does not match Table <table_name_here>.  
Cannot add fields (field: actions.list)
```

What's the proper way to define this schema?  My data coming in is in json format like

```
{
    "recordName":"name_here", 
    "date": "2020-01-01", 
    "actions": [
        {
            "id":"1", 
            "name":"aaa", 
            "last":"bbb"
        },
        {
            "id":"2", 
            "name":"qqq", 
            "last":"www"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Hello, 

You can try this to match the schemas, if the schema in BigQuery is similar to the schema on Spark:

`finalDf.write.mode("append").format("bigquery")...mode("append").save()`. 

On the other hand, if this does not help you, the schemas may be different between Spark and BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue when the connector is used on the default settings with Parquet format used as an intermediate later (see [similar bug report](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/251)).

Changing the format to ORC solves the issue:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.datasource.bigquery.intermediateFormat", "orc")
```